# Angular 2 gives SystemJS cannot find /angular2/http module

Tags: angular, systemjs

I have created a service for Angular 2:

```
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";
import {Http} from "angular2/http";
import {TaskModel} from "./tasks.model"

@Injectable()
export class TasksDataService {

  tasks:Array<any>;

  constructor(http:Http) {

    this.tasks = [
      new TaskModel("Dishes"),
      new TaskModel("Cleaning the garage"),
      new TaskModel("Mow the grass")
    ];
  }

  getTasks():Array<any> {
    return this.tasks;
  }
}
```

When I run my program the browser shows:

`system.src.js:1049 GET http://localhost:3000/angular2/http.js 404 (Not Found)`

I have looked up tutorials and they include angular2/http the same way. Does anyone see what is going wrong?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to check that you include the `http.dev.js` file in your main HTML file:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
```

You need then to add the HTTP_PROVIDERS as second parameter of the bootstrap function:

```
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/http';

bootstrap(MyMainComponent, [ HTTP_PROVIDERS ]);
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thanks! But this triggered another error: angular.js:12477 Error: No provider for Http! (Tasks -> TasksDataService -> Http). I read about including it as a provider for a component, but this one is just a class. Any clues?

Comment: You need to add HTTP_PROVIDERS as second parameters of your bootstrap function ;-)

Comment: I have read that. But this is a Angular 1 hybrid app. So my bootstrap looks like: adapter.bootstrap(document.body, ["app"]); and adapter.bootstrap(document.body, ["app", HTTP_PROVIDERS]) did not work :)

Comment: Perhaps try to put it within an array: [ 'app', [ HTTP_PROVIDERS ] ]

Comment: Great thought but didn't work. However I will create a new question for this issue

Comment: Yes, you're right. Good idea. I will follow your question because I'm interested in the answer ;-)

Comment: This is the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749090/how-to-add-http-providers-to-an-upgradeprovider-bootstrap-in-angular-2

Comment: @ThierryTemplier, how would I do it using Angular 2 RC1 instead of Beta? Thank you very much!

Comment: @LuisGouveia with RC versions, Angular2 modules (like HTTP) are configured within the SystemJS configuration. See this link https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html (`systemjs.config.js` file).