# How to add HTTP_PROVIDERS to an UpgradeProvider bootstrap in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I use:

```
let adapter: UpgradeAdapter = new UpgradeAdapter();
[...]
adapter.bootstrap(document.body, ["app"]);
```

To bootstap my Angular application. Now I need to add HTTP_PROVIDERS to this. I have tried many variations but none did work including:

```
adapter.bootstrap(document.body, ["app", HTTP_PROVIDERS]);

adapter.bootstrap(document.body, ["app", [HTTP_PROVIDERS]]);
```

Does anyone know the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
adapter.addProvider(HTTP_PROVIDERS);
```